# How to sync content items in XC9?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I noticed that configuration settings, e.g. `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront`, (and probably also other configuration settings) are not synced to the commerce database (ie. `[SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments].[dbo].[ContentEntities]`) by the EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths REST call.

In the log the following error occurs:

```
74 21:06:12 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.ContentPathAlreadyExists: Text=Content path '/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel' already exists.
```

Currently the only workaround I found was to re-initialize the environment.
This is clearly not desired in a production environment.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the following answer from Sitecore Support:

EnsureSyncDefaultContentPaths should be run only once when the environment is just set-up. For the subsequent configuration updates you should use the SynchronizeContentItem DoUxAction from the ContentApiSamples collection in Postman:

As body put the following data:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#Sitecore.Commerce.EntityViews.EntityView",
    "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.EntityViews.EntityView",
    "Name": "SynchronizeContentItem",
    "Policies": [],
    "DisplayName": "SynchronizeContentItem",
    "EntityId": "Entity-ContentPath-Commerce Control Panel",
    "Action": "SynchronizeContentItem",
    "ItemId": "",
    "Properties": [
        {
            "Name": "Version",
            "Policies": [],
            "DisplayName": "Version",
            "Value": "2", // to find the exact version you should pass here you should run "Sync Item" GetEntityView request from the Postman.
            "IsHidden": true,
            "OriginalType": "System.Int32",
            "IsReadOnly": true,
            "UiType": "",
            "IsRequired": true
        },
        {
            "Name": "Path",
            "Policies": [],
            "DisplayName": "Path",
            "Value": "/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront",//itemPath for the item you want to update.
            "IsHidden": false,
            "OriginalType": "System.String",
            "IsReadOnly": false,
            "UiType": "",
            "IsRequired": true
        }
    ],
    "ChildViews": [],
    "DisplayRank": 500,
    "UiHint": "Flat",
    "Icon": "chart_column_stacked"
}
```

Comment: Other workaround is to delete all records from the `ContentLists` and `ContentEntities` tables and all records containing `'content'` in its Id from the `CommerceEntities` table. After this perform a iisreset, and the tables will be automatically populated again.